# WPF: how to set infinity symbol as content for a label?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a label. As the content I want to set the infinity symbol. How can I achieve that?

[image]

Comment: Oh, so that's what an infinity symbol looks like. :)

Comment: Yes for those who don't know it I linked it so that nobody can overlook it ;)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
<Label Content="&#x221E;" ... />
```

FYI: [XML Character Entities and XAML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748250.aspx)

Comment: That's exactly the whole solution I was looking for!

Answer (score 4):

Like this:

```
<Label Content="&#8734;"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

The [infinity symbol](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/221e/fontsupport.htm) is represented by the unicode character 221e.  If you follow the link it shows fonts that support the character.  It seems like most popular fonts do, including Arial, which I think is the default font for labels.

Answer (score 1):

Somethig like this (might need to specify size of the image):

```
<Label>
    <Label.Content>
        <Image Source="URI to Image"/>
    </Label.Content>
</Label>
```

Edit: Since you posted a picture i assumed you have an image, if you want the symbol as text say so.

Comment: Thanks but I would prefer to do this without an image.

Comment: Well, as expected the text solution is there already so no need to change this...

Answer (score 1):

See here: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/221e/index.htm

Comment: Thanks, and which one should i use?

Comment: An answer with just a link is a poor answer. It doesn't give any more information and a Google search and becomes useless when the link breaks.

Comment: Gabe you are right, will add some more information instead of a link only in my furure answers, thanks for pointing this out ;-)